# Deploying a Maven Spring Boot project on a server offline

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a situation in hand where I have no internet connectivity on my client's server (because it is an intra-net server) and I have to deploy my Spring Boot application on it which uses Maven build. The thing is, I am not allowed to connect the server to the internet due to security reasons but I am able to access internet on my development machine. So I have two questions:

- How do I get all the dependencies on the server in question? Can I somehow copy the downloaded files from  my development machine to the server? If so, how?
- Do I need to setup Apache Tomcat or should I just run the war file from the command line? What are the best practices?

Comment: First *make jar not war* (especially with Spring Boot I would say and to quote the good Josh Long here). Also just build the artifact on your machine (or build server) and simply copy the jar to the server do `java -jar your.jar` and well that is it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sounds interesting. Could you elaborate on that(I mean buildig the artifact on my machine) and post it as an answer? :)

Comment: just build your app on development/CI machine that has internet access and deploy the final jar/war to client's server. there is no need for maven on client's server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make a jar file instead of making a war file. That should help you to run without Tomcat since it embeds a web server.

Dependencies are packed with the jar when you do a Maven build. You need to have an internet connection to build it. Copy the jar to the production environment and run.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server) is striaght forward example to deploy spring boot application on tomcat server

Follow the example and add one more tomcat6/tomcat7 plugin

```
            <!-- Tomcat 6 plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${serverUrl}:${port}/manager</url>
                    <path>/${contextpath}</path>
                    <username>${username}</username>
                    <password>${password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

plugin properties as follows

```
<properties>
        <!-- Server Details -->
        <serverUrl>http://kpServer</serverUrl>
        <port>8080</port>
        <contextpath>kp-cxf</contextpath>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password></password>

        <!-- Skip test execution during default steps -->
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
```

And you can use `mvn tomcat6:redeploy` command to deploy to your server(in shore maven deownloads plugins/dependencies from internet to your development server, when you run mvn tomcat6:deploy/package it creates war by taking jars from you local maven directory)

Comment: Do I need to add the tomcat plugin if I package the entire thing as a jar file? AFAIK a Spring Boot project can be packaged as a jar file ad run if JDK is present.

Comment: tomcat plugin is added advantage, in one command you can deploy, else you need to copy the war to tomcat servers webapps directory manually. Also not tomcat6 and tomcat7 has different plugins, Go through the link, it explains to follow number of steps like change packaging to war, add modify entry point to enable servlet init, commneting out spring boot plugin etc.

Comment: I had already converted the packaging to jar but then reverted back according to the comment by M.Deinum earlier : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295206/deploying-a-maven-spring-boot-project-on-a-server-offline/30297349?noredirect=1#comment48687299_30295206

Comment: Not sure about that, You may try those approach as well

Comment: This answer is irrelevant given OP uses Spring Boot which does all this out of the box.